# firefox border-width 1px issue

Tags: css, firefox

```css
div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 99999px;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

When I use `border-radius: 1px` & `border-color: white`
I can see the thin outline of `background-color`

twitter and youtube has a notification icon with `border-radius: 1px` & `border-color: white` and it looks really bad :(

[twitter notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oU2aX.png)

This does not happen in the chrome browser. Is this a known issue or is this working as intended?